# Type Error: A float is required

Tags: python

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Running...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    print('Alice:\n Net pay: $%7.2f' % alice.calculate_pay())
TypeError: a float is required
```

Weird error, that I have no idea on what to do. I'm obviously beginning with Python, and thus far bug tracking has been easy, minus this. Here's the code below:

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self):
       self.wage = 0
       self.hours_worked = 0

   def calculate_pay(self):
      self.calculate_pay = (self.wage * self.hours_worked)


alice = Employee()
alice.wage = 9.25
alice.hours_worked = 35
print('Alice:\n Net pay: $%7.2f' % alice.calculate_pay())

bob = Employee()
bob.wage = 11.50
bob.hours_worked = 20
print('Bob:\n Net pay: $%7.2f' % bob.calculate_pay())
```

Comment: Did you try that codes without float numbers? Because I think its not going to work either. Try it with normal numbers please. Like 9-35. Your function has no return

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `return` statement:

```
def calculate_pay(self):
  self.calculate_pay = (self.wage * self.hours_worked)
  return self.calculate_pay
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `calculate_pay` method and its not returning anything, means it return `None` by default.

Please return value from function and use it or use variable instead or method

**Variable Use**

```
alice.calculate_pay()
print('Alice:\n Net pay: $%7.2f' % alice.calculate_pay)
```

**OR**

*Return from function*

```
def calculate_pay(self):
    return (self.wage * self.hours_worked)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
def calculate_pay(self):
    self.calculate_pay = (self.wage * self.hours_worked)
```

to

```
def calculate_pay(self):
      self.calculate_pay = (self.wage * self.hours_worked)
      return self.calculate_pay
```

The initial one is not callable and equals `NoneType`. Even though the value stored to `self.calculate_pay` is float you cannot reference it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method and instance variable to different names, and make return statment in your calculate_pay method:

```
def calculate_pay(self):
    self.calculated_pay = (self.wage * self.hours_worked)
    return  self.calculated_pay
```